# Ckeditor converting `$()` to '%28%24%29'

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

To ignore special characters I've added below config to config.js :

```
config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = false;    
config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = false;    
config.forcePasteAsPlainText = false;    
config.pasteFromWordPromptCleanup = false;
config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;    
config.entities = false;
config.basicEntities = false;
config.entities = false;
config.entities_greek = false;
config.entities_latin = false;
config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;
config.entities_processNumerical = false;
```

But characters string `($TEST)` is being converted to `%28%24TEST%29` when click save.

Is my config incorrect ?

Alternatively where in the src is ckeditor making the code conversions so I can just hard code it to ignore these characters : `$()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the Advanced Content Filter (http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter)? Maybe in specific http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent?